# Is there any closed form expression for this finite summation?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I came across a finite sum that writes down as
$$\sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} (i+2)!$$
Is there any closed form expression for this sum?

Comment: Try putting the first few values into OEIS.

Comment: @Ian: thank you, I was unaware of this [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=212%2C1370%2C10112%2C84158%2C780908%2C8000882&sort=&language=&go=Search) site. The solution is$$\lfloor(n+1)\times(n+1)!\times e\rfloor-\lfloor n\times n!\times e\rfloor$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OEIS sequence [A001340](http://oeis.org/A001340) is your sequence. It is also twice sequence [A082030](http://oeis.org/A082030) which has a hypergeometric expression so your sequence $a(n)=2\:_2\!F_0(3,-n;;-1)$. There are other expressions in the OEIS entry such as $a(n)=b(n+1)-b(n)$ where $b(n):=\lfloor e n n!\rfloor$.